# Textbox losing data within HeaderTemplate on Postback in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, textbox

I have a ASP.Net GridView and I build the column collection myself. Within the column collection I have a HeaderTemplate and within there I have a textbox which I use to filter the records in the grid.

When I enter text within this textbox and perform an action on the grid which causes a postback (i.e. changing the page) I lose the text within my textbox.

Anybody got any ideas as to why this data is lost?

My ASP code for the header template is below:

```
<HeaderTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="Number" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="textBoxNumberFilter" runat="server" />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="buttonFilterNumber" runat="server" OnClick="buttonFilters_Click" />
</HeaderTemplate>
```

Thanks in advance. I'm using ASP.Net 4.0

Answer (score -2):

I think this might help.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38714/How-To-Perpetuate-Dynamic-Controls-Between-Page-Vi